# How to create unique code based on current date in php

Tags: php

I have a question, how to create/generate unique code based on current date or input date? For instance, input date = 02-02-2022, the code supposed to look like 20220202-000001.

Comment: And may I guess? The next unique code has to be `20220202-000002`?

Comment: Requirements are very vague. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @CodeSpirit: True, in questions people always say **what** they want to do, never **why**, even though the **why** is crucial for answering a question correctly.

Comment: If you just use the date object, to check for microseconds, then it is almost surely unique and already a date format

Comment: yes indeed. the next unique code has to be 20220202-000002 and so on.

Comment: What i want to accomplish is the user know how many visitor per day. something like that

Comment: If you just get the microtime you'll almost never gonna have a duplicate

Comment: "What i want to accomplish is the user know how many visitor per day." Something like that or exactly like that. Couldn't you then just store each "visit" to database, together with a date and count them by date when needed? Or just store them as date, visit_count and increment the visit_count when needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date object using [the inegrated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)DateTime API.
[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) you can find a list of available formatting options

Answer (score -1):

THIS solution only shows one way to solve the OP's specific problem:

*"I have a question, how to create/generate unique code based on current date or input date? For instance, input date = 02-02-2022, the code supposed to look like 20220202-000001.".*

**THIS solution does not attempt to create a UID across any/and all problem domains.**

You could use `str_replace()` on the date to get rid of the dashes. Then use `str_pad()` on the count to fill it with 0's and have it "right justify" the actual count.

```
<?php

function makeCode($date, $count) {

    $dateCode = str_replace("-", "", $date);
    $countCode = str_pad(strval($count), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    
    return $dateCode . "-" . $countCode;
    
}

// test

echo makeCode("02-02-2022", 1); // 02022022-00000001

?>
```

The 2nd parameter to `str_pad()` controls the width of the counter, how many zeroes will fill minus the string length the count intself.